# Unable to hash password in Django Backend

Tags: python, django, hash, passwords

I created a custom user model because i needed the user to sign in using email instead of username. If a user signs up on the frontend, the password is hashed just fine but when i try to create a password from Django's backend, the password is saved as plain text.

admin.py

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    # Save the provided password in hashed format
    user = super(RegisterForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password"])
    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```

forms.py

```
class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Confirm Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email',)

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        qs = User.objects.filter(email=email)
        if qs.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("email is taken")
        return email

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password and password2 and password != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegisterForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password'])
        # user.is_applicant = True
        user.is_active = True  
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

Please for some assistance.

Comment: Change this: `user = super(RegisterForm, self).save(commit=False)` to this: `user = super().save(commit=False)`

Comment: @Ahtisham thanks but this isn't working

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: @Ahtisham no error but still saving password as plain text

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should create the user using the official function see create_user . https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user

Comment: I created a custom user model because I needed the user to sign in using email instead of username. 

I updated my post with this info

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `def save` to this in your User creation form in admin.py,

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super().save(commit=False)
    user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password'])

    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```

Comment: Have you changed your code to this? In your edited question you have still `user = super(RegisterForm, self).save(commit=False)` this line